# (discord.js) discord bot that removes any message containing the regex anywhere in the message

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So basically what i'm trying to do here is use a discord bot to automatically remove any discord message sent in the server that contains an ip even if it's not valid/out of range.
upon removal the channel is warned not to post IP's..
I have this to test if it works but am not having any luck can anyone help?
(the issue i'm having is trying to set up in discord.js not with the regex, i want it to remove anything between 0.0.0.0 - 999.999.999.999)

client.on('message', message => {

```
let regex = (/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/);
    if (regex.match(message.content))  {
        message.channel.send("Don't post IP's in chat!")
}
```

Comment: You should use `message.delete(timeout)`, where `timeout` is the number of milliseconds you want to wait before deleting it. (In this case, presumably 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegExp.prototype.match()` is not a function; I believe you're looking for [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 let regex = /([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/;
 if (regex.test(message.content)) {
  message.channel.send("Don't post IP's in chat!");
 }
});
```

---

You might also be thinking of [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), which would be the other way around:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 let regex = /([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/;
 if (message.content.match(regex)) {
  message.channel.send("Don't post IP's in chat!");
 }
});
```

However, `RegExp.prototype.test()` is the most efficient in this situation.

---

To delete the message, use [`Message.prototype.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete):

```js
if (regex.test(message.content)) {
 message.delete();
 message.channel.send("Don't post IP's in chat!");
}
```

Comment: you're an absolute legend, i've been searching for an entire day and everyone has given me complex answers that don't work or make sense, this literally fixed my issue in ten seconds thank you & yes you're right i was thinking of String :/

Comment: Glad I could help!